# Two Azure VM clones have different processor

Tags: azure

I have two Ubuntu 16.04 Azure VMs created from the same image, in the same region (WestEurope), configured to be the same size (Standard A1, 1 vcpus, 1.75 GB memory) and created at the same time (days of difference).

Inspecting the CPU info they are completly different, one being a Intel and the other AMD:

First VM

```
>cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 8
model name  : AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4171 HE
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xffffffff
cpu MHz     : 2094.724
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 5
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl cpuid extd_apicid pni cx16 popcnt hypervisor lahf_lm cmp_legacy cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw retpoline rsb_ctxsw vmmcall
bugs        : tlb_mmatch fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg amd_e400 spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 4189.44
TLB size    : 1024 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 44 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Second VM

```
>cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 63
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0xffffffff
cpu MHz     : 2394.456
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 15
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm pti retpoline fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms xsaveopt
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips    : 4788.91
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 44 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

For me is a big problem because one VM does not have AVX instructions support and a program depending on tensorflow fails to run.

**How can this be happening?**

**Is there no guaranty to get the same VM processor for 2 different VMs?**

Comment: If you want to run Tnesofrlow, you should pay for a VM that delivers that.One of the GPU ones - NV, NC, NCv2, NCv3, ND - not sure they actually are more expensive (as your work will finish significantly faster)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft don't have a nice matrix to figure it out across all types, but certain compute types are limited to specific processors.

[For example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-sizes-specs):

- Dv3 are restricted to Intel Xeon E5-2673 v3
- A8-A11, H, are restricted to Xeon E5-2670
- G is restricted to Intel Xeon, but unspecified exactly which ones

Sometimes you can find [Microsoft blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2014/11/11/azure-a-series-d-series-and-g-series-consistent-performances-and-size-change-considerations/), which is about as official as you can get, that can give you more information. In this case that blog states that A-series VMs are undefined in their CPU architecture.

With all this in mind, the closest match you'll find with guaranteed Intel processor is `Standard_D2_v3` at around twice the price.